# C programming - character move issue

Tags: c, for-loop, char, move

```
void shiftChar(char** text, int length, int height){

 int i, j;
   for ( i = 0; i< height ; i++ ) { 
    for (j = 0; j<length; j++){
      if(text[i][j] == 'X'){
     ;
      }
    }
  }           

}
```

Hey people, can someone please point me in the right direction here.. I'm trying to shift some characters(in any random direction). I'm new to C and having trouble visualizing what needs to happen here..

This is the structure of my function will be called in my main.

and so if the file is 
ABCDEX 
ABCDEX
ABCDEX
ABCDEX
I need to shift the X characters over like so,
XABCDE 
XABCDE
XABCDE
XABCDE

Comment: only `for..loop` code? `I'm trying to shift some characters in a file` where is `file` related stuff? who calls `shiftChar()`?. ask question with proper details.

Comment: This is an algorithmic problem, you should come up with the solution yourself. Hint: use insertion sort technique.

Comment: Do all the contents in your file have a fixed pattern?  Or are you trying to shift a given character in every word that it occurs one position left or right?

Comment: thank you, I will look into insertion sort. And I am trying to sift through contents of a file for a character, shift them to the left of the row , in which case from upstairs,'length'.

Comment: Look for algorithms like this [one](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/Sorting/insertionSort.htm) (Emphasise on the while in the pseudocode).

Answer (score 0):

It's quiet difficult to understand what you have to do with your function..

Do you have to shift the X to left ? Start from the end of the array and change values between the **n** and **n-1** element. One by one..

Answer (score 0):

```
static inline void swap(char *x, char *y){
    char tmp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = tmp;
}

void shiftChar(char** text, int length, int height){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i< height ; i++ ) { 
        for(j = 0; j<length; j++){
            if(text[i][j] == 'X'){
                int k;
                for(k = j;k != 0; --k){//k != 0 && text[i][k-1]!='X' If the 'X' there is more than one
                    swap(&text[i][k-1], &text[i][k]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I understand you want to do, for each string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "ABCDX";
    char tmp;

    /* C99 for loop */
    for(int i = strlen(str) - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        tmp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[i + 1];
        str[i + 1] = tmp;
    }

    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```